# Horizontal rule/line beneath each <h1> heading in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a 100% horizontal line (rule) automatically beneath every instance of an

```
 <h1>
```

header tag using CSS.

Example of what I'd like to see:

--- snip 8< ---

Introduction

---

--- snip 8< ---

I have this in my CSS:

```
.mypage .headline {
    font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica", san-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And I have this in my main HTML page:

```
<body class="mypage">
<h1><span class="headline">Introduction</span></h1>
```

I cannot figure out how to have a horizontal line appear beneath every use of the headline class.

Comment: use border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

Comment: Is there a practical purpose to the span?  If not, the headline class should go on the h1 (though it seems a touch redundant as the H in h1 means heading...)

Answer (score 45):

You can also try using Pseudoclass [:after.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after) . I have used this kind of styling in one of my applications.

http://jsfiddle.net/ffmFQ/

```
h1:after
{
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

You can tidy up little more to style something like this:- http://jsfiddle.net/5HQ7p/

```
h1:after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border:2px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

```
h1 { border-bottom: 1px solid black }
```

Adjust size and colour to preference.

Answer (score 11):

You should use the `border-bottom` CSS property.

For HTML, use the below code:

```
<h1>Introduction</h1>
```

For CSS, use the below code:

```
h1
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

In case, you want to use the `float:left, float:right` properties, then you have to use `width:100%` property also. `padding-bottom` is to optionally give some space between the text and horizontal line.

```
h1
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

Code Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aASQe/

Answer (score 4):

`border-bottom` is what you need... and to modify the distance of the line from the text, use `padding-bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `border-bottom`? You can remove the span then too..

HTML:

```
<h1 class="headline">Introduction</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #666;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling something is going wrong, you can use `zoom: 1;`. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbdjT/)**

(I have removed `span` but you can set class to your h1 tag.)

#### CSS

```
h1 {
    font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica", san-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

HTML...

```
<h1>Introduction</h1>
```