# How do I position/place my <hr> line underneath my <h1> header?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms

> This is my css code:
>   The hr line must be directly underneath the h1 heading

```
#Logo{
    position: relative;
      background: url(/IMAGES/Photo\ by\ aldain-austria\ on\ unsplash.jpg);
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }

 #Logo h1{
 position: absolute;
 top: 26%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
 }
```

> The following is my html:

```
 <div id="Logo">
   <h1>Basil Carolus</h1>
   <hr>
  </div>
```

Comment: Refer to the following Stack Overflow article for information about border-bottom in CSS. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073323/horizontal-rule-line-beneath-each-h1-heading-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are not setting any styles for the hr tag, but instead of using an hr, I may recommend setting a border for the h1 element, like so:

```css
#Logo{
    position: relative;
    background: url(/IMAGES/Photo\ by\ aldain-austria\ on\ unsplash.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

 #Logo h1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 26%;
 border-bottom: red solid 4px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div id="Logo">
   <h1>Basil Carolus</h1>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positions can be a little tricky.  When you make a position absolute you remove it from the the DOM flow and hence it's height (for the absolute element) isn't used to calculate the height of the wrapper.  Also for the hr element you need to specify a width.

Since an h1 is font-size 55px we make the div height 55px and remove margin from the h1 tag. Then we can absolute position the h1 to the top of the div and the hr to the bottom of the div.  Notice we need to offset the hr the 5px

```css
#Logo{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:55px;
    padding-bottom:15px;    
}

 #Logo h1 {
     width: 100%;
     position:absolute;
     text-align: center;
     top:0;
     margin:0;
 }
 
 hr{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     width:100%; 
     border:solid 1px black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="Logo">
   <h1>Basil Carolus</h1>
   <hr>
 </div>
```